# Kohana 3.2: Undefined variable title

Tags: framework, php, html, kohana

Начал изучать kohana и сразу влип... не могу загрузить файл из views... выдает ошибку. Вот код

```
class Controller_Index extends Controller_Template {

    public $template = 'v_index';

    public function action_index()
    {
       $this->template->title = 'Интернет-магазин';
       $this->template->content = 'Главная страница';
    }
    public function action_catalog()
    {
       $this->template->title = 'Интернет-магазин';
       $this->template->content = View::factory("v_catalog");//тут проблема...
    }

}
```

Код файла v_catalog.php

```
<h4><?= $title ?></h4>
<table border='1' width='80%'>
<thead>
    <tr>Наименоание</tr>
    <th>Цена</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Товар 1</td>
        <td>100 руб</td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <td>Товар 2</td>
        <td>200 руб</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Подскажите, в чем дело? Скриншот с ошибкой тут

[image]

Comment: В чём заключается эта ваша проблема? У Коханы такой прекрасный вывод ошибок, а вы ни слова оттуда не скопировали.

Comment: пожалуйста

Comment: другое дело

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Какой хороший пример того, что **всегда надо** приводить ошибку. С чего вы взяли, что ваш view не грузится? Его же текст фигурирует в тексте ошибки.*

Проблема в том, что вы не передаете в отображение переменную `$title`, о чём вам и пытается сказать сообщение `Undefined variable`.

Присваивание переменной происходит так:

```
$this->template->content->title = 'Заголовок';
```

Comment: разобрался...спасибо

Comment: Удачи в изучении. Прошу прощения, если показался грубым.

Comment: да все норм...не сахарные

Answer (score 0):

Может проблема здесь в `v_catalog.php`:

```
<h4><?= $title ?></h4>
```

Правильнее было бы:

```
<h4><? echo $title; ?></h4>
```

А этот код потом будет работать без проблем:

```
$this->template->title = 'Интернет-магазин';
$this->template->content = View::factory("v_catalog");
```

Comment: @Asad, вы подняли не самый свежий вопрос, на который уже дан верный, судя по словам автора, ответ. Да еще и написали непонятно что - замена одного вида тегов на другие ничего не даст, по той причине, что свойство ``$title`` всё равно остается без значения.